# How do I increase the speed of an upload to Firebase Storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload 15 images to my Firebase Storage. However, this operation takes a lot of time.

I want to optimize this process. Is there any way to optimize the upload speed?

Comment: Reduce the size/quality of the image or increase the internet speed.

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Comment: If the Firebase transfer speed is the bottleneck, use "store and forward" with a fast intermediate server

Comment: you can try a combination of firebase upload with the async task. run number of the async task each task will have separate upload at the same time.

Comment: @Himeshgoswami if i run async task for multiple file,it will take same time because internet speed is now divided between all async task

Comment: Can you clarify 'takes a lot of time'? Is that 5 seconds? 5 hours? 5 days? What's the size Mb of your images? Is there a coding issue that may be related to the upload? Can you include you uploading code so we can take a look? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try to compress the image before upload, this way image size will be reduced. Upload and download speed will also improve.

Found this [site](https://www.android-examples.com/compress-bitmap-image-in-android-and-reduce-image-size/) that explains how you can do this.